# Azure Data Studio-server connection error on Mac bookpro

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, azure-data-studio

To run SQL Server on my Mac, I installed Docker and SQL Server Management Studio (Azure Data Studio) and got connected to the server. However, when I tried to reconnect another time, I got the error below. I've found much advice about how to fix the issue on Windows, but not on Mac.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

Increase Docker memory from 2 GB to 4 Gb from Preferences then again run the following commands,

docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

Now, launch an instance of the Docker image.

docker run -d --name name_your_container -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rd' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Developer' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest